# jquery: pull different content from different divs with same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery noob, so don't kick too hard plz.
Got the product grid with table in product description. Table td's have the same class, and when i try to pull the content from each of them and insert into a different place, i still get the same content, where it varies in each product.

here is html

```
<div class="product">
<div class="product777">
<table>
<tr><td class="varimage1">content 1</td><td class="varimage2">COntent2</td></tr>
</table>
<div class="galitem1"></div>
<div class="galitem2"></div>
</div></div>
```

here is the piece of js code

```
$(".product").each(function(){
// tried this
var colorimgab = $(".varimage2").html();
//and tried this
var colorimgaa = $(this).closest(".product777").find(".varimage1").html();
$(".galitem1").html(colorimgaa);
$(".galitem2").html(colorimgab);
  });
```

Comment: What is `.product` and `.product777`?

Comment: edited. Messed up the simplified code

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you:

```js
$(".product").each(function(){
  var colorimgab = $(this).find(".varimage1").html();
  var colorimgaa = $(this).find(".varimage2").html();
  $(this).find(".galitem1").html(colorimgab);
  $(this).find(".galitem2").html(colorimgaa);
});
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product">
  <div class="product777">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="varimage1">content 1</td>
        <td class="varimage2">COntent2</td></tr>
    </table>
    <div class="galitem1"></div>
    <div class="galitem2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```